# Changing master email address in Artifactory

Tags: email, admin, service-accounts, account

When we signed up to JFrog to test artifactory, i used my work email address.

After testing, we signed up for a Pro subscription, and it's all working as we need.

The issue is that now i'd like to change the email address to a service account email address, but don't seem to be able to action this anywhere in the portal.

Can someone let me know how I go about this?

David

I've tried to change the email address in my JFrog cloud profile, but it doesn't seem to update it, I can only sign in with my work one, not the service account.